# Using FragmentActivity throws InflateException

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

Common Fragment to be used in 2 Activity's

```
public class Ads extends Fragment {
    private View rootView ;
    private MoPubView adView ;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ads, container, true) ;
        adView = (MoPubView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.adView) ;
        adView.setAdUnitId(LogoQuizUtil.MOPUB_AD_UNIT);     
        adView.loadAd();
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Fragment layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ad_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="bottom" >

    <com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="bottom" />    
</LinearLayout>
```

Other Layout where I include this fragment

```
 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/ads"
    android:name="myPackage.Ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="bottom" />
```

I get a dont get a exception when I call setContentView (R.layout.ads) the first time, when the second activity calls the fragementactivity (Ads) I get a exception at setContentView (R.id.ads).

Exception I get is

`08-07 09:38:30.359: W/System.err(975): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mypackage/mypackage.SecondActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #263: Error inflating class fragment`

Comment: Show the code for your fragment.

Comment: Its up there Ads extends FragmentActivity

Comment: You need to research fragments then.  That is **not** a fragment.  That is a class from the support library to let you create an activity that can use fragments.  A fragment will extend the fragment class.

Comment: I modified it to a Fragment, same exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets start at the beginning.  An activity is not a fragment and a fragment is not an activity.

You need an activity to contain/control fragments.  To do that you extend `Activity` (for Honeycomb+ development) or use the support library and extend `FragmentActivity`.  In this class you would use `setContentView` to set the layout that will contain the fragment(s).

You then, from that class, call the fragment manager (`getFragmentManager` or `getSupportFragmentManager` depending on which class you have extended).  The fragment manager is then used to create, attach and detach the fragments.

The fragment, not being an activity, is coded differently.  It should have an `onCreateView` method that inflates the layout for the fragment and returns it to the fragment manager from the activity.

Then it is typical to use `onActivityCreated` for the rest of your code (or whatever else is needed).

Making the changes to use fragments properly may or may not solve all of your problems, as I see you are using some kind of custom widget in your layout and the issue could be there too.

Comment: I'll update the answer with the correct code in a while. Thanks.